# FTP CloudConnect Source Example?

Tags: gooddata

I have a customer that wants to include csv files that are parked in a FTP site that I need to pull into my graph.  Does anybody have an example of the best way to attack this??  Thanks!

Comment: Just figured it out through the 'Remote Files' portion of the CSV reader.  Doah!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSV_READER or FILE_DOWNLOAD CC component
with target url:
ftp://${FTP_USERNAME}:${FTP_PASSWORD}@${FTP_SERVER}/${PATH_TO}/*.CSV